# multiple-value http.PostForm() in single-value context in go

Tags: go

While using `net/http` and `net/url` for single key value I am getting this error

```
multiple-value http.PostForm() in single-value context
```

Comment: Can you give some context?  What code caused the error?  What was the input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error possibly caused by single-value assignment — [PostForm](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.PostForm) (both for `Client` and `Response`) returns `(resp *Response, err error)` (value and an error), so you need to do something like:

```
resp, err := http.PostForm("http://example.com/form", url.Values{"key": {"Value"}, "id": {"123"}})
```

while you doing (my suggestion)

```
resp := http.PostForm("http://example.com/form", url.Values{"key": {"Value"}, "id": {"123"}})
```